Configure touchbar to only show when holding the function key
I have a 2020 Macbook Pro that comes with a Touch Bar.
I'd like it to be normally empty and inert, because I keep touch it by accident. When I hold the "fn" key, I'd like it to show the expanded control strip and be able to use it for things like sound volume control, etc.
The closest I get is to put the normal behavior to function keys (which I don't want or need, and I keep touching them by accident).
Is it possible to accomplish the behavior I want?
It's pretty annoying that Apple didn't put a "Disable" option for the touchbar in their Touch Bar setup dialog box for default behavior. That would precisely be what I need!
